# Pip for python3.8 has weird dependency

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I'm seeing the following error when trying to run `pip` after having just installed, on MacOS:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 584, in _build_master
    ws.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 901, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 792, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.VersionConflict: (pip 20.1.1 (/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('pip==20.0.2'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/opt/python@3.8/bin/pip3", line 6, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3255, in <module>
    def _initialize_master_working_set():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3238, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3267, in _initialize_master_working_set
    working_set = WorkingSet._build_master()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 586, in _build_master
    return cls._build_from_requirements(__requires__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 599, in _build_from_requirements
    dists = ws.resolve(reqs, Environment())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 787, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'pip==20.0.2' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

What should I do to correct that?

Comment: There might be a mismatch between the `pip` script that has been called and the version of _pip_ actually installed. You might want to reinstall _pip_ with `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --force-reinstall pip`. Then I'd suggest reading the following articles: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/ -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: So I've done that reinstall, but I'm getting the same error message after.

Comment: I had similar issues with Python 3.8 on a Mac. I fixed it by downgrading to 3.7.

Comment: @Frank As always, I would recommend just not using the `pip` scripts at all, ever. Instead always be explicit: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip somecommand`. As explained in the articles I linked. There are often issues with some kind of mismatch in the `pip` scripts, they are less reliable than `python -m pip`.

Comment: @sinoroc - it _does_ work a lot better the way you suggest. I've updated my scripts to use `python -m pip` now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad it helps. Having `pip` script is great when working from an interactive command line as are all short commands, since it's faster to type. But for everything that goes into a file (scripts, documentations, etc.) I'd recommend anyone to always use the longer explicit unambiguous versions (for example `rm --recursive --force` instead of `rm -rf`). Anyway, I don't understand why the reinstall didn't fix it. Maybe you'd want to try some of the other install options: `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip install --force-reinstall --ignore-installed --upgrade pip`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just reinstall Python, I had that issue and it worked for me. Another solution, that I didn't test is using this python file https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py. You could also install it by brew or easy_install(I heard it will be deprecated)